# zap tool showing security vulnerability but we can't find those vulnerability in our source code?

Tags: sql-injection, zap

vulnerability showing as:-

1. SQL Injection - SQLite

**Method:** GET

**Parameter:** query

**Attack:** ' | case randomblob(10000000) when not null then "" else "" end --

**Evidence:** The query time is controllable using parameter value [' | case randomblob(10000000) when not null then "" else "" end --], which caused the request to take [542] milliseconds, parameter value [' | case randomblob(100000000) when not null then "" else "" end --], which caused the request to take [900] milliseconds, when the original unmodified query with value [query] took [167] milliseconds.

2. SQL Injection - Oracle - Time Based

**Method:** GET

**Parameter:** query

**Attack:** field: [query], value [query and exists (SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_name('10.0.0.1') from dual union SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_name('10.0.0.2') from dual union SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_name('10.0.0.3') from dual union SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_name('10.0.0.4') from dual union SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_name('10.0.0.5') from dual) -- ]

3. Advanced SQL Injection - Oracle AND time-based blind

**Method:** GET

**Parameter:** query

**Attack:** query AND 2972=DBMS_PIPE.RECEIVE_MESSAGE(CHR(113)||CHR(65)||CHR(80)||CHR(114),5)

4. SQL Injection - MsSQL

**Method:** GET

**Parameter:** query

**Attack:** query WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:15' --

5. SQL Injection - Hypersonic SQL - Time Based

**Method:** GET

**Parameter:** query

**Attack:** field: [query], value ["; select "java.lang.Thread.sleep"(15000) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'SYSTEM_COLUMNS' and COLUMN_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME' -- ]

6. SQL Injection - PostgreSQL - Time Based

**Method:** GET

**Parameter:** query

**Attack:** field: [query], value [case when cast(pg_sleep(15) as varchar) > '' then 0 else 1 end]

7. SQL Injection - MySQL

**Method:** GET

**Parameter:** query

**Attack:** query / sleep(15)

8. Advanced SQL Injection - PostgreSQL > 8.1 stacked queries (comment)

**Method:** GET

**Parameter:** query

**Attack:** query;SELECT PG_SLEEP(5)--

9. Advanced SQL Injection - Oracle stacked queries (DBMS_PIPE.RECEIVE_MESSAGE - comment)

**Method:** GET

**Parameter:** query

**Attack:** Feb 2018;SELECT DBMS_PIPE.RECEIVE_MESSAGE(CHR(105)||CHR(122)||CHR(102)||CHR(108),5) FROM DUAL--

10. Advanced SQL Injection - Microsoft SQL Server/Sybase time-based blind.

**Method:** GET

**Parameter:** query

**Attack:** query) WAITFOR DELAY CHAR(48)+CHAR(58)+CHAR(48)+CHAR(58)+CHAR(91)+CHAR(83)+CHAR(76)+CHAR(69)+CHAR(69)+CHAR(80)+CHAR(84)+CHAR(73)+CHAR(77)+CHAR(69)+CHAR(93) AND (1972=1972

All of our source code following the given Example:-

`public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
        @Query("select u from User u where u.firstname = :firstname or u.lastname = :lastname")
        User findByLastnameOrFirstname(@Param("lastname") String lastname, 
                             @Param("firstname") String firstname);
}`

Comment: Can you add the ZAP issue details? The fact that so many of the SQL based rules are reporting something makes it more likely that its a real problem and not a false positive.

Comment: Also, you can look on the history tab and view the request and response, This could help you understand why Zap report SQLi.

Comment: @SimonBennetts I have added the details.

Answer (score 3):

Pick one of the timebased attacks and rerun it - you can do that by rightclicking on the alert in ZAP and selecting 'Open/Resend with Request Editor'.
Check to see how long the request took (its shown at the bottom of the dialog) - was it the same time (or a bit more) than the delay that the attack is using?
If so try increasing the delay and resending - is it now taking the longer period of time?

If the time is being affected by the time specified in the attack then you will have an SQL injection vulnerability.

Why havnt I said anything about the source code you posted? Thats because I have no idea if thats all of the relevant code :)

You might also want to try using a static analyser on your code - it will probably show *loads* of false positives, but you can just focus on any SQL injection vulnerabilities it reports.